# datepicker selected date does not trigger javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

i want to create filter date (from and to) with required attribute if one of the filter (from,to) is filled. I am using jquery datepicker for date selection.

here is my code:

```
 $(document).on('change', "#from", function () {
     if ($('#to').val().length == 0 && $('#from').val().length == 0) {
         $('#from').removeAttr('required');
         $('#to').removeAttr('required');
     } else if ($('#to').val().length != 0 || $('#from').val().length != 0) {
         $('#from').attr("required", "true");
         $('#to').attr("required", "true");
     }
 });

 $(document).on('change', "#to", function () {
     if ($('#to').val().length == 0 && $('#from').val().length == 0) {
         $('#from').removeAttr('required');
         $('#to').removeAttr('required');
     } else if ($('#to').val().length != 0 || $('#from').val().length != 0) {
         $('#from').attr("required", "true");
         $('#to').attr("required", "true");
     }
});
```

here is the code for the textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.startdate, new { @class = "datepicker form-control", @id = "from", @placeholder = "Select From Date" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.finishdate, new { @class = "datepicker form-control", @id = "to", @placeholder = "Select To Date" })
```

this code is working perfectly if I type some text in the from and to textbox.
However, it is not working for the datepicker. I don't understand why the date selected from datepicker does not trigger the javascript. Anyone know why?

Comment: i think the change listener u have attached is with the input box and when u select the date is it reflecting in the input box ? Please check that the listener is triggered when u are selecting the date

Comment: yes, it is not triggered. That is why I am asking why it doesnt trigger the javascript. And please let me know if you have solution for this

Comment: i think u dont have to check on click instead check on submit of the form

Comment: yes you are correct. it was my mistake not realize that. thank you!